# distribution update made my close/minimize/maximize window buttons diappear

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, window-buttons

I am running an ubuntu/gnome3 environment. While running the upgrade manager on 12.04, I was informed that there was a distribution update but that it was partial. (whatever that means)

After a few failed attempts at updating through the manager, I decide to run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get update`. The updates seem to work however, the close/maximize/minimize buttons of all windows have disappeared. I also can no longer use the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> function.

I tried to post an image but I need more rep (sorry)

I have tried to run the updates again but nothing changes. I'm still very new at this. I would appreciate it if you could use simple terms to describe or ask questions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: @JorgeCastro: it seems to me that whether it is a bug or not, his first objective is to fix the problem so he can get back to work in a normal manner.  Aren't we here to help with that, or do we just chastise him and make him wait for help elsewhere?

Comment: Did you lose the entire titlebar, or just the buttons?  If just the buttons, try changing themes, then change back to see it that will fix it.

Comment: It looks like the buttons have been replaced by "File, Edit, View, go, bookmarks and help drop down menus.

Comment: What is your gnome version?

Comment: Open terminal and run this command ' gconftool-2 --set /desktop/gnome/shell/windows/buttom_layout --type string :close '

Answer (score 2):

I can think of 2 tools that might help you: **GNOME Tweak Tool** and **gconf-editor**.

Both are available for free in the Software Center, and once their installed, you can open them by <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> and then typing their names.

GNOME Tweak Tool is the simplest one to use.

In gconf-editor, the settings for the close, maximize, minimize buttons are under:

> **apps → metacity → general**

I can't guarantee this will help, but it might at least point you to the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for responding Alex. 

I've tried changing themes in Gnome-Tweak-Tool. The themes change but the buttons don't come back.

I've looked at gconf-editor and the settings are correct "button_layout      close,minimize,maximize:"

I'll read-up on how to report bugs since you can't ask questions on askubuntu (who knew?) but any other advise would be greatly appreciated.